# Search Contract not in VS2013, alternative?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I want to add a search contract to my Windows Store App. I'm using VS2013 and several different tutorials instruct me to choose PROJECT > Add New Item... and then select the Installed > Visual C# > Windows Store category which, they say, should include an item "Search Contract"

It's not present in my plain vanilla installation. There *is* a "Search Results Page", which I have tried adding, but which doesn't seem to set up any contract boilerplate or add the requisite manifest entry.

[image: No Search Contract]

Am I nuts, am I using the wrong version of something or is there some installation I have yet to perform?

Breaking news, it's only missing from VS2013. It's present and operational in VS2012 which leaves me with the burning question:

**Why is Search Contract missing from VS2013 and what am I supposed to use instead?**

Experimenting with VS2012 I notice that the when you select the old "Search Contract" template the suggested file name is SearchResultsPage1.xaml which implies that this template was simply renamed to "Search Results Page". But it doesn't seem to work any more.

Several sources, including magincandre1981 below and a Microsoft staffer (on another Q+A site) have told me that apps providing search to the search charm is defunct and now it's in-app only.

Yet this is contradicted by the fact that the Win 8.1 samples contain a working example of implementing the Search contract.

Andre points out that users have reported that the search charm causes 100% CPU usage.

I can believe this. Essentially the OS calls into your app. Most of WinRT is designed to make it impossible to ruin the user experience by being selfish and stupid, but in this case there's nothing to limit our excesses, and it is entirely possible to wreak havoc. My own code is fully async, but getting this to work required me to learn several things, deferral in particular.

In that context, pulling the feature would be a predictable move for MS... yet they didn't. The sample above *works*. Talk about mixed messages!

Comment: [Maybe you could inspect this VS2013 sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Search-app-contract-sample-118a92f5).

Comment: I have that sample and it compiles and runs fine using VS2013. Unfortunately it's a bit had to diff that with a dysnfunctional app created via VS2013. I can successfully use VS2012 to add Search Contract to a project and then return to VS2013 but I am trying to work out what's broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Windows 8.1 your app must implement search on your own](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2013/08/16/windows81-contentindex/).

> From now on, the Windows Store apps are fully responsible for
>   implementation of the in-app search functionality - Search Charm does
>   not support Search Contract and does not trigger in-app search anymore
>   To facilitate this new design pattern, WinRT for Windows 8.1 includes
>   a new search box UI control and a set of APIs for indexing and
>   searching application data.

Comment: Um, thank you... I think. But how can that be so when does the search charm demonstrably *does* honour the search contract for apps written with the older tools? Very puzzling, now delving into the material you referenced.

Comment: Gahhhh now I really want to hurt someone. Unified extensible search was brilliant. Now we're back to just web and file-system. This is the difference between google search and yahoo's arbitrarily structured data. Sure they can open my app but they'd have to remember that. Users are notoriously disinterested in learning anything that won't get them laid. I can just about get them to remember the search charm because it's only one thing to remember.

Comment: A Microsoftie agrees with you on another site on which I posted more or less the same question, but I cannot find an official Microsoft statement to corroborate that article, and there is a Search Contract sample in the Windows 8.1 samples: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Search-app-contract-sample-118a92f5. So now I don't know *what* to think.

Comment: I don't code Store Apps, I only searched a bit for search changes because several users reported that the search charm causes 100% CPU usage by the Explorer .